# Using spark divide a dataset into 2 based on sum of a column value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My spark dataset is like below. I want to divide this into 2 datasets such that they contain the same or almost the same `value` column when summing up the `value` column.

```
id,value
1,20
2,30
3,50
4,10
5,20
6,10
```

I want to divide this into 2 datasets such that first dataset looks like: Sum of `value` is 70

```
id,value
1,20
2,30
4,10
6,10
```

2nd dataset:Sum of `value` is 70

```
id,value
3,50
5,20
```

The idea here is to sum the value `column` and the 2 datasets should almost contain equal sum of values.
Any help? Looks like a complicated one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the dataframe using the average. It's not as good as your answer, but  should give a good enough solution for a general case.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

mean = df.agg(F.avg('value')).collect()[0][0]
df1 = df.filter(F.col('value') > mean)
df2 = df.filter(F.col('value') < mean)

>>> df1.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  2|   30|
|  3|   50|
+---+-----+

>>> df2.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   20|
|  4|   10|
|  5|   20|
|  6|   10|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks could you help convert `mean = df.agg(F.avg('value')).collect()[0][0]` to java?